# google maps api not working in ie7

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer-7

I have a google map on my site, it works well on firefox or chrome but on ie7, it just displays a grey box, you can check it on this url :

http://pavillonm.okarito.com/default/chiffre/pavillon

I thought about a js conflict with maybe respond.js but no. I removed some javascript to check but it still display a grey box.

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

It's not GoogleMap. You pinitit.js having problem with eventListener

Comment: I tryed to not load this file, so there is no more js error but google maps remain grey